# Install SQL server 2012 Express through Installshield silently or Unattended

Tags: sql-server-2012, web-deployment, installshield

My Objective is to Create the `setup.exe` file of web-application. When User run this `setup.exe`, it will install `SQL server` silently or Unattended on user machine, deploy web site and configure it on `IIS`. I'm using Install shield for this. But not understand how to setup configure `SQL server Express 2012` for silently or Unattended installation.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can add a prerequisite for silent installation of SQL server Express 2012 by passing proper arguments to it. For this prerequisite you can add argument `"/s /qn"`. You can edit your prerequisite using prerequisite editor. Or you can use a CustomAction for server installation.

To configure this server after installing it, you can use `INIFileChanges` or `TextFileChnages` in InstallShield to configure the files.

For deploying it on IIS, whatever commands require to do this, you can add those commands in CustomAction. You can use `LaunchAppAndWait()` utility in CustomAction.

Comment: Thanks for replay. you are right. it have completed by editing prerequisite.

Comment: It this helps you then please mark this answer as accepted. So other readers can follow the same.